# IAL TSF :SP>D KJG: RF??PD G <SLHDO{

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

$\text{RPDA:D JDPRZ G  HSLqK VLS< <JAK KS HS!}$

$\text{<JAK PALUFAUD G: KJG: } \text{ALT<AT}\{ $

Please consider any capitalisation as intentional.

Also apologies if you were reading my last version, I had some minor errors.

Comment: You can use backslash to escape from brace matching. Change last part to this. `AT\{ }$` I wasn't sure if this is what you wanted, so didn't make the edit myself.

Comment: @Lafexlos Exactly what I wanted, thanks! Completely forgot about the backslash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post and its title use

> [Dvorak encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_encoding). With [this handy site](http://wbic16.xedoloh.com/dvorak.html), we can decode the message as follows.

```
IAL TSF :SP>D KJG: RF??PD G <SLHDO{
```

> CAN YOU SOLVE THIS PUZZLE I WONDER?

```
RPDA:D JDPRZ G HSLqK VLS< <JAK KS HS!
```

> PLEASE HELP: I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO!

```
<JAK PALUFAUD G: KJG: ALT<AT{
```

> WHAT LANGUAGE IS THIS ANYWAY?

Comment: Very well done.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, you're right. This wasn't particularly tricky. I just don't think many people saw it.

Comment: I don't think many people saw it either. How long did it take you to get it anyway?

Comment: About 10 minutes. I knew it looked familiar, at first, and when I figured out what it was, I started to manually decode it, but then was like "Duh. Surely someone's made an online encoder/decoder." Then the last few minutes was spent trying to get the darn formatting to work in quote blocks, until I gave up, and just made 'em code blocks. :-)

Comment: At least the bounty wasn't completely in vain then. I was sure that in a site of many many users that someone must have recognised it, but I just didn't want the question to keep going unseen forever.